# Facebook App without owner

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Suddenly I couldn't find my Facebook App in Developer Apps section, I used my 'App Access Token' to get the app roles through Facebook Graph API but the surprise was that my app has no owner, I think someone got my 'App Access Token' and removed all the admins from the app, The problem is [My Facebook App has no owner]. any ideas to get it back ?
[Facebook Applications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles)

Comment: your app is so useful that Mark took it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a graph API bug, because '**Must specify at least one developer who has administrator permission.**' error dialog would pop up if you delete the last admin(you) on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/roles. Report the bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, and also ask them how to contact for recover your apps.