# How can I get owner email for a Facebook App using the App Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, app-id

How would I get the email address associated with an active Facebook App ID, if all the usual methods (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338996/how-can-i-find-the-owner-of-a-facebook-app-id#30595303), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346951/facebook-graph-api-returning-only-id-and-name)) don't return any email information with my creator-uid?

(I simply don't get the email field returned, even when I specifically request it as per [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/). I don't think this is a case of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891410/facebook-app-without-owner) as I didn't get an "App has no owner" error, or any error whatsoever.)

I've also tried [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&version=v3.0), but I'm in a catch-22 as I can't log in to select the application first.

I'm looking for the owner email address, so I can log in to make administrative updates following [graph API updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.12).

**Other specifics:**

I get the following when I hit the Graph API via: [https://graph.facebook.com/{my-app-id}?access_token={my-access-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bmy-app-id%7D?access_token=%7Bmy-access-token%7D) or [https://graph.facebook.com/{my-app-id}?access_token={my-access-token}&fields=email](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bmy-app-id%7D?access_token=%7Bmy-access-token%7D&fields=email)

> {
>       "name": "my-name",
>       "id": "my-creator-uid" }

I've tried to [recover my FB account](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover&lwv=110) using all emails I can think of, but FB says 'no account exists' for each that I try. (This is a data-analytics corporate account being used to gather data for 12+ months, so I can't simply create a new account/app ID and start using that instead, as app-scoped user IDs will change.)

I've also tried viewing [https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{my-creator-uid}/](https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/%7Bmy-creator-uid%7D/) and [https://www.facebook.com/{my-creator-uid}/](https://www.facebook.com/%7Bmy-creator-uid%7D/) from another company FB account, but both get:

> Sorry, this content isn't available right now The link you followed
>   may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience
>   you're not in.

What else would you suggest? What might have happened? I've tried to contact Facebook, but that search led me to [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462953/9723247), so I'm here. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no `email` field on the application node. Try `contact_email`, and hope that whoever set this up used the same address for that, as with their Facebook account …? _“What might have happened?”_ - sounds like you/your company made the rather common mistake, of setting up fake accounts for administrative purposes. You are only allowed one personal account, and it has to be “real.”

Comment: way too late on this, but did you try https://graph.facebook.com/{creator_uid}?access_token={APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question, try to get in touch with the Facebook Team, if you are working with Facebook paid services (like Advertising) you might have an account representative that can accelerate the things a little bit (But this can be a really long wait).

A more realistic option is to create a new profile and an new app, also your application will be reviewed as well (Take a little less time than previous option).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your help. As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462953/9723247 I'm posting here with these tags - it seems to be the only way to get in touch with FB representatives. If we create a new profile and new app, are there ways to link and unify data collected from the two apps? I'm very worried about app-scoped user ids.

Comment: You are linking to a 5 year old post. https://facebook.stackoverflow.com doesn't exists anymore it just links to normal stackoverflow.

Comment: Correct, it is old, but it redirects to the tag 'facebook' here, and more importantly it still seemed to me like the only option after my searching and Googling. However, I certainly might have missed something. Do you have an alternative, beyond Daniel's suggestion about ad reps?

Comment: @MSmith it's a reboot, if you have your own database, it will be not a problem, but if it relies only on Facebook, for storage, you will start from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean 'reboot'? We do indeed have our own database; we don't rely upon FB for storage. However, if we collect data with a new app, and then have existing prior collected data from an old app, these cannot be unified, yes?